# Libraries cordova build

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, terminal

I have created an application with the Android framework "Cordova". It's all right until the command "cordova build". The terminal gives me this:

```
Running command: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build 
Buildfile: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.1.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/francesco/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.1.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/francesco/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found modified input file
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found modified input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
      [dex] input: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-9316ddc44c6caff34f21734b49d7a8f5.jar <- /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar
      [dex] Found modified input file
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (7 defs/2,2KiB) with dex B (223 defs/326,2KiB). Result is 230 defs/400,0KiB. Took 0,4s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating MainActivity-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
[apkbuilder] Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/francesco/.android/debug.keystore (Permesso negato)

BUILD FAILED
/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:973: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:312: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Unable to get debug signature key
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getDebugKey(ApkBuilder.java:279)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:392)
    at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 4 seconds

/home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/francesco/cordova-plugman/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/francesco/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

The problem would seem to be the libraries (but not sure), but should be installed with the command "sudo npm install -g cordova". Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Between the lines thatthe terminal gives me back there is also:

```
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
--------------------------------------
-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

```
Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/francesco/.android/debug.keystore (Permesso negato)
```

Looks like this is a permissions error, and it is having issues reading from the .android folder.  You can check the permissions using `ls -l` You also not be the owner of that folder, which you can change using `sudo chown -R $USER /home/$USER`